# Show that $z\sin\frac{1}{z}$ is unbounded on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=z\sin\frac{1}{z}$ for $z\neq0$ and show that if $|z|<1$ the function is unbounded, here is what I've tried, let $z=x+iy$

$|z\sin\frac{1}{z}|=|z||\frac{e^{\frac{i}{z}}-e^{\frac{-i}{z}}}{2i}|=\frac{1}{2}|z||\frac{e^{i}-e^{-i}}{e^{z}}|\geq\frac{1}{2}|z||\frac{e^{i}}{e^{z}}|=\frac{1}{2}|z|e^{-x}$,

I don't see a way I can say it is unbounded as $x^2+y^2<1$

Comment: it's easier to use $w=1/z$ and show that $\sin w/w$ si unbounded for $|w|>1$ which follows by putting $w=ix, x>1$ and noting that $|\sin ix| >(e^x-1)/2, x>1$ etc

Comment: @Conrad thanks but a dumb question why can we pick $w=1/z$ is it because $|z|<1$?

Comment: $|z|<1$ implies $|w|>1$ but the main reason to do this change of variables is because the term $\sin 1/z$ is harder to understand at the first glance than $\sin w$

Comment: @Conrad I see now that this change of variable makes the formula easier to work with, but why can we pick w to be this specific form $ix$ and then conclude the result hold for all $|w|>1$? thanks!

Comment: Unboundness means that for every $R>0$ there is $w$ st $|f(w)|>R$ and that's what we show with $w=ix$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is incorrect:  $$e^{\frac iz}-e^{-\frac iz}\neq\dfrac {e^i-e^{-i}}{e^z}$$.

(Just stop at $\lvert\dfrac z2\rvert (e^{\frac iz}-e^{-\frac iz})$.

Then simply let $z=\dfrac 1{ki}$ and use that $n=\mathscr o(e^n)$.  That's $\dfrac n{e^n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.  You could even use L'hopital. )

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, can you let me know what is k a real number or complex? and also what does $o(e^n)$ mean? thanks!

Comment: Hi.  Sure.   $k$ is a positive integer.   As I said $n=\mathscr o(e^n)$ means $\dfrac n{e^n}\to0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\frac 1  {in} \sin (in)=\frac 1  {in} \frac {e^{-n}-e^{n}} {2i}$. Can you show that $|\frac 1  {in} \frac {e^{-n}-e^{n}} {2i}| \to \infty$? [$\frac 1  {in} e^{-n} \to 0$  and $|\frac 1  {in} e^{n}| \to \infty$].

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $f(z)=z\sin\frac{1}{z}$ has an **essential singularity** at $z=0$. Now, in any neighborhood of $z=0$, $f(z)$ attains at most all the values in $\mathbb C$ infinitely often  with at most one possible exception (*Picard's Big Theorem*).